# How to check if database table is empty using the anchor's onclick event?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, onclick

I want to know how to check if the table is empty using the onClick event of an anchor tag? 
HTML look like this:

```
<a href="#" title="Movies" onclick="function goes here">Movies</a>
```

If the table is empty, it will display a confirmation box asking the user if he wants to continue or add some list. How do I do that? Connecting to MySQL database using JavaScript is not highly advised, can you help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX to invoke a PHP script?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: no, I have not yet. I am just starting to learn AJAX, though.

Comment: Then that's your best solution for now. Go study it and invoke a PHP script that checks if the table is empty, and work with that

Comment: do you want to connect to the database using Javascript?

Comment: Google AJAX, invoke a PHP script via that and that's it. You shouldn't ask for complete code that you can copy/paste. However, I bet there are rep hunters who will do just that.

Comment: use Node.js along with `https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP script tells you if the DB table is empty and once you know whether it is or it's not, you use an `if else` to write different `onclick` handlers on your HTML elements.

If you need the HTML cached and not generated on every request, **AJAX is your only choice**. And PHP still handles things but returns a meaningful JSON to your JS for further handling.

Connecting to MySQL from JS, not even sure if it's possible, it's a security risk 100%. Your name will turn from **ladybug** to **ladysecuritybreach**.